# Oracle XMLType and BinXMLProcCache causes memory leak?

Tags: java, oracle, memory-leaks

I have a lack of experience with Oracle DBs, but now I am investigating interesting issue.
I think there is a problem with T4CConnections leaked in BinXMLProcCache object used by XMLType class.
Google says he knows nothing about that pair of keywords: *XMLType "BinXMLProcCache" memory leak*, so I am asking here for some help.
To be short with issue details: Spring's JdbcTemplate is used to work with datasource. Oracle ojdbc6 11.2.0.3.0, xdb6 11.2.0.3.1.

```
public SomeDoc store(Document doc) throws DataAccessException, JAXBException {
    XMLType xmlType = null;
    Connection connection = null;
    SomeDoc someDoc = null;
    try {
        LOGGER.info(doc.toString());
        MapSqlParameterSource mapSqlParameterSource = new MapSqlParameterSource();
                                     //I've hided some fields
        mapSqlParameterSource.addValue("F1", something, Types.VARCHAR);
        //... more fields
        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.marshal(doc.getData(), stringWriter);
        String xml = stringWriter.toString();
        try {
            connection = dataSource.getConnection();
            OracleConnection oracleConnection = connection.unwrap(OracleConnection.class);
            xmlType = XMLType.createXML(oracleConnection, xml);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            throw new UncategorizedSQLException("XML conversion error", "", e);
        }
        mapSqlParameterSource.addValue("FIELDS", xmlType);
        //... and some more fields
        namedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(SQL_STORE, mapSqlParameterSource);

        someDoc = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(SQL_GET_DOC_BY_REF,
                new MapSqlParameterSource("DOC_REF", doc.getDoc_ref()), someDocRowMapper);
    } finally {
        if (xmlType != null) {
            try {
                xmlType.free();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }
        if (connection != null) {
            try {
                connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }
        if (xmlType != null) {
            xmlType.close();
        }
    }
    return someDoc;
}
```

I've looked at contents of heap dump using Eclipse MAT, and noticed some interesting situation: there is a lot of T4CConnections in memory.
Future investigations led me to this picture:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/izvvrys124xjb8l/AACGyIDg6c2miwjrIu8-aGH-a?dl=0 (with low reputation I can't post more than two links, so pictures is in my dropbox album, sorry).
So, I've read http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/memory.pdf , and now I understand the way Oracle choosed: memory in trade for performance.

But I also thinking now, that if pool evict connections that are idle for some time (look at dbcp's minIdle and maxIdle options) - there will be some growth of new connections in memory. With all of this things with buffers in memory to speed up driver performance, BinXMLProcCache creates a memory leak. It's key is T4CConnection, and value don't matters now. BinXMLProcCache is stored in static field of XMLType, and it stores WeakHashMap, which keys are never cleared and it create memory leak, I think.
Is my investigation correct?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have refreshed my knowlege about WeakHashMap: "Hash table based implementation of the Map interface, with weak keys. An entry in a WeakHashMap will automatically be removed when its key is no longer in ordinary use. More precisely, the presence of a mapping for a given key will not prevent the key from being discarded by the garbage collector, that is, made finalizable, finalized, and then reclaimed. When a key has been discarded its entry is effectively removed from the map, so this class behaves somewhat differently from other Map implementations."

Comment: But it still doesn't matters, because WeakHashMap can grow until there is no more memory.

Comment: It means that keys are weak-linked too, but it still doesn't matters, because WeakHashMap in our scenario will grow until there is no more memory. And only then it will start to free it's keys.
I mean that there is no difference hom many memory you will give to app. It will always be full of unused garbage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/* *Found my own question, and will answer it myself, as there is a solution exists for this problem.* */
So, the problem was indeed in driver for Oracle.
From the Oracle site:

```
Bug 17537657 Memory leak from XDB in oracle.xdb.SoftHashMap
The fix for 17537657 is first included in 
12.2 (Future Release)
12.1.0.2 (Server Patch Set)
12.1.0.1.4 Database Patch Set Update
12.1.0.1 Patch 11 on Windows Platforms

Description
When calling either getDocument() using the thin driver, or getBinXMLStream()
using any driver, memory leaks occur in the oracle.xdb.SoftHashMap class. 
BinXMLProcessorImpl classes accumulate in this SoftHashMap, but are never
removed.
```

So, just apply a fix from Oracle, and issue will gone away.